# How are route url generated in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried running the command `rake routes` and i get the below list.

> ```
> F:\My-Projects\Personal\odot>rake routes
>                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern
>         Controller#Action
>     todo_list_todo_items GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)
>         todo_items#index
>                          POST   /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)
>         todo_items#create
>  new_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/new(.:forma
> t)      todo_items#new
> edit_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id/edit(.:
> format) todo_items#edit
>      todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:forma
> t)      todo_items#show
>                          PATCH  /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:forma
> t)      todo_items#update
>                          PUT    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:forma
> t)      todo_items#update
>                          DELETE /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:forma
> t)      todo_items#destroy
>               todo_lists GET    /todo_lists(.:format)
>         todo_lists#index
>                          POST   /todo_lists(.:format)
>         todo_lists#create
>            new_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/new(.:format)
>         todo_lists#new
>           edit_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id/edit(.:format)
>         todo_lists#edit
>                todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)
>         todo_lists#show
>                          PATCH  /todo_lists/:id(.:format)
>         todo_lists#update
>                          PUT    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)
>         todo_lists#update
>                          DELETE /todo_lists/:id(.:format)
>         todo_lists#destroy
>                     root GET    /
>         todo_lists#index
> ```

How are these url's generated?. I looked back at `config/routes.rb` and could find only these lines.

```
Odot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items
  end

  root 'todo_lists#index'
end
```

For instance:

```
todo_lists#destroy  DELETE /todo_lists/:id(.:format)
```

How is this url generated automatically for the destroy event?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, `resources` route is a short way to define RESTful routes. It will give you the full implementations of CRUD operations in your database.

See the docs here: [CRUD, Verbs, and Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Those are restful routes, the "resources" lines in your routes file add them.
You can find more info on the topic [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)